# What to use for writing a user interface?

Tags: java, user-interface

I've written a series of classes to interperet data from a serial port.  This data needs to be displayed on the screen.  I am trying to go for straight up eye candy with a refined look.

Swing UI- Easy to program, yields mediocre results
Open GL- Hard to program, yields good results.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) a go, the API is a lot simpler than Swing.  Here is [a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306190/java-desktop-application-swt-vs-swing) outlining the differences between SWT and Swing.

Comment: I prefer SWT over Swing but, if the OP doesn't like Swing results, he won't like SWT too. Unless he takes the hard way and goes for a eclipse 4 RCP App...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any alternatives, but in my opinion it is possible to write beautiful GUI with Swing. Just changing the ugly default look and feel goes a long way. Visual appeal just doesn't seem to be a top priority for most Java coders and therefore you have to make an effort to make anything pretty.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaFX](http://javafx.com/samples/) maybe? Didn't tried it yet, it obviously offers some eye candy.

Comment: From what I've looked at, JavaFX does look very good. Not sure how easy it is to use, but definitely worth a look

Comment: I'd give JavaFX 6 to 12 months to see where it is going or if it is going to stay alive in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetBeans combined with [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) (Java bindings for OpenGL) or simply with Java2D.

NetBeans has an easy [GUI Builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) for Swing applications -- you can make beautiful interfaces (if you get into it), easily change the Look&Feel, etc etc.., and you can use Java2D or JOGL for visualizing your data and embed it in the GUI to display it.

There's a plugin for JOGL for NetBeans so getting started is hassle free.

Answer (score 0):

use html, css, javascript.  Much easier to get wizz-bang UI than using Swing or related technologies.

Answer (score 0):

For my projects at work, we have purchased a licence of  [JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/).
This is really a great tool that saved us a lot of time.

Writing Swing application by hand can be a real pain and is awful to maintain.

This tool choose the right approach : The model-view-controller. 
The GUI builder creates XML files for you that represent the interface. These XML files are loaded at runtime and transformed into Swing objects. The builder also generates Java stubs that you can fill with event handlers.

It also handles Localization and nice layout goodies.

Give it a try.