# How to "Open" and "Save" using java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to make an "Open" and "Save" dialog in java. An example of what I want is in the images below:

Open:

[image: Open file dialog]

Save:

[image: Save file dialog]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The question is valid; don't downvote just because someone is not a native English speaker. Instead post a comment how to improve the question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would suggest looking into `javax.swing.JFileChooser`

Here is a site with some examples in using as both 'Open' and 'Save'.  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm

This will be much less work than implementing for yourself.

Answer (score 65):

You want to use a `JFileChooser` object.  It will open and be modal, and block in the thread that opened it until you choose a file.

Open:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(modalToComponent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
  // load from file
}
```

Save:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(modalToComponent) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
  // save to file
}
```

There are more options you can set to set the file name extension filter, or the current directory.  See the API for the `javax.swing.JFileChooser` for details.  There is also a page for "How to Use File Choosers" on Oracle's site:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: Whatever component you want it to be modal to goes there.

Comment: @Arnold: Or just replace `modalToComponent` to `null`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could take a look at [JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), which allow you to use native dialogs in one line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an introduction to [file dialogs in the Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). Java2s also has some [example code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrationofFiledialogboxes.htm).

Answer (score 2):

First off, you'll want to go through Oracle's tutorial to learn how to do [basic I/O in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

After that, you will want to look at the tutorial on [how to use a file chooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider the possibility of using SWT (another Java GUI library). Pros and cons of each are listed at:

[Java Desktop application: SWT vs. Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306190/java-desktop-application-swt-vs-swing/2306275#2306275)