# Making an save and open button in Java that saves and opens .txt

Tags: java, file, notepad

I am 11 years old and I hope to do Java as a career, and I am making a Notepad like program in Java. Everything is functional except save and open button of the menu bar.
Okay it works but I don't know the code for the save and open button. Can someone please give me the code (and actually explain it)

Comment: Read the file chooser tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza While that certain provides an answer to part of their question, I'm not sure it answer all parts of the question - IMHO - Still a good link

Comment: It might seem harsh, but as a learner, we're going to encourage you to have a go first.  When you get stuck on a particular problem, then ask a question, demonstrating what it is you have tried.  This way we can guide you better.  If you want to know why we do it this way, have a read of [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

create a  `JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();` on open button click

This is already answered Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548140/how-to-open-and-save-using-java)

Comment: Please flag the question as duplicated instead of using the link as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at [`JTextComponent#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [`JTextComponent#write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29), which will save you a lot of work and time.

Next, take a look at [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write action listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and lastly, take a look at [How to use file chooers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)