# Exporting pdf file using Crystal report (Allow user to choose file path)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I know how to export to pdf using Crystal Report, but I don't want to preset file path, I want users can choose file path (and file name) when clicking Export button.

Do you know how to do that ?

Thank you very much,

Tai

Comment: Do you mean like a `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: @OneFineDay: yes, you know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompting the user for a save location would be something you'd implement as part of your app - [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548140/how-to-open-and-save-using-java) provides some answers on how to do that.  Then, you'd just supply the path from the dialog to the Crystal Reports export API so it saves to that location.

Comment: Thank you. I found a way that similar to HttpRespone, but not found

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial code in my project. I hope it helps.

```
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    'saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF files (*.PDF)|*.PDF"
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            'Here is where you write the file 

        Catch Ex As Exception
            'MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)

        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open. 
        End Try
    End If
```