# Desktop application on Java

Tags: java, user-interface, desktop

I want to create a desktop application, but do not want to use SWING. I have heard about of SWT as alternative to SWING. Any another solutions exists? And what do you recommend to use?

Comment: What makes you not want to use Swing?  That would help others propose alternatives.

Comment: 1) Accept answers to your questions. 2) Why do you not want to use Swing? Explaining why this is not a good option for you will give people a better idea of what to suggest.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate Q. Has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306190/java-desktop-application-swt-vs-swing

Comment: @Dmitriy 7 questions and no accepted answers ? Have to be kidding

Comment: In my opinion SWING is too bulky. To write simple things it requires writing a lot of routine code. Although it is possible misperception caused by the fact that I just do not can compare with any other framework, because havent experience.

Comment: Why do you write Swing in all uppercase. Is it some sort of abbreviation or are you shouting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an [Eclipse Rich Client Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/rcp.php) (RCP), using SWT and JFace.

Answer (score 1):

What about just AWT in `java.util.awt` and subpackages?  You can use the older equivalents of Swing's components.