# GUI programming in Java for Windows?

Tags: java

What is the best approach for making GUI applications for windows with Java?

Is it [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) and [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29)? Or is it outdated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Desktop application: SWT vs. Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306190/java-desktop-application-swt-vs-swing), which has a good comparison between the two.

Comment: if its windows only then you could also look at WPF with c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are starting from scratch and don't have any experience one way or another I suggest looking into [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/). It is Oracle's declarative user interface similar to XAML and Flex. I believe it will eventually surpass AWT, Swing and SWT.

While Swing may be common when using Java, more often than not it leads to slow and bulky user experiences. I cannot suggest using Swing.

#### Why JavaFX

- The user interface is declarative; you don't have to write Java code. This allows for some really great user interface builders to be constructed, because it can process the UI without having to compile or process Java.
- The user interface is easily separated from business logic, allowing for separation of concerns and paradigms such as MVVM, MVC, etc.
- Hardware acceleration support.
- Transition effects between controls. Something that would take substantial amount of code in Swing.

Download page:

[JavaFX and Scene Builder Developer Preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)

I realize OS X and Linux are still in the development preview stage, but I'd still pick that over using Swing.

Comment: It looks like JavaFX is - currently - Windows exclusive. Is that correct? Anyone know of a porting timetable? Could use something like that for HP-UX...

Comment: @MikeAdler They have Mac OS X and Linux Dev Preview. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html I believe the OS X is pretty solid, the Linux one will be a few more months before GA.

Comment: :) Guess this is what i was looking for... I did not want to use Visual studio.. And swing was looking vintage to me...

Comment: @Andrew Finnell: Can we develop JavaFX applications with Eclipse ? Guess i saw in the website that we can use only Netbeans..

Comment: I am not sure how they can limit you to netbeans. Its an SDK. Its possible all the designer tools only work in NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

AWT is rarely used. Most GUI development is done in Swing these days. If you're so inclined, there are a couple halfway decent GUI-Builders for Swing out there.

Edit: Honestly, I should have said 'Pure AWT is rarely used'. It is, after all, the basis for Swing.

Answer (score 2):

The most common modern GUI toolkits for Java are [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [SWT](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SWT/article.html). Swing is included in the standard JDK, and is less hassle to deal with. If you just want to build Java GUIs fast (à la Visual Basic), try the [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) IDE with [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), or the [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) IDE.

Comment: Time for an update?

Answer (score 0):

[Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) is the way to go, as it is the newer version that fixed AWT's weaknesses; and there are many great tutorials, [such as here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CD8QFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing&ei=42KVT4TpEoPF6QG_2KG_BA&usg=AFQjCNEtbuJqikUwLj2JRyfcUkFgDrCI8w).

See here also - [Oracle Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html).