# How to make GUI java beautiful?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am struggle to make a beautiful GUI in java. As you may know the default look and feel are not attractive that's why I would like to ask if there are existing mechanism or tools to do it thank.

Edited:

I want to develop chart application.

Comment: which framework are you talking about? SWT, Swing?

Comment: You have to provide more information if you want useful answers. What kind of an application are you developing? What libraries are you using?

Comment: If you're comparing swing vs. swt, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306190/java-desktop-application-swt-vs-swing

Comment: You hire a good designer and apply lots of elbow grease. (Take, for instance, IntelliJ IDEA which goes a long way with the "native" LaFs and custom controls made to fit into it.)

Comment: I  use Swing , I want to build chart application ..

Comment: [Filthy Rich Clients](http://www.filthyrichclients.org)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what framework you're using. If you're using Swing you can use [**Java Look and Feel**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html). There are some really nice one's out there but [**here's a link**](http://geeknizer.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10/) I found from a simple Google search. I like the Sea Glass one :) [**This**](http://dlemmermann.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/the-best-swing-look-feel-bizlaf/) also seems pretty informative and might help you out a little

Comment: thx, Do you know any framework that allow me to build a chart application ??

Comment: There are GUI builders available for most IDEs, but to use them well, you need to understand the layout managers.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What are these "layout managers"? Are you referring to something in Java Graphics, or...?

Comment: @Ungeheuer There are these wonderful things known as search engines. Visit your favorite one, plug in 'layout managers' and add 'java' and go from there. While it may be true there are no stupid questions, there are certainly lazy and poorly researched ones, and that is a classic example.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was unsure if you were referring to some tool that would come with an IDE, or if it was an aspect of Java that you were referring to. Unless there's a Google for your brain, I'm not sure how I would find the answer...

Comment: @Ungeheuer So it's one of two possibilities. Wow.. shouldn't expect you to Google **two** things. Attention spans are shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search **Swing Synth**, maybe it's what you want.